# Unanswered question button not working

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

Clicking the "unanswered" button brings up lots of questions that already have answers?

[image: unanswered button not working]

Comment: Ah. But do they have a ✔️?

Comment: or upvotes @JourneymanGeek